# Adding a new column in the output

Tags: mysql

I have a table demo. with columns FirstName, LastName, ReportsTo, Position, Age. I need to print the details from the table with the following conditions.
Query should return all the records if ReportsTo is either JennyRichards or null and sort by age.
Also my query should return a new column BossTitle and it should be CEO if ReportsTo is JennyRichards else it should be null.

I tried the following query but it is returning a syntax error.

```
select 
  FirstName, LastName, ReportsTo, Position, Age, 
  BossTitle as (select IF(ReportsTo='JennyRichards','CEO','')) 
from demo  
where ReportsTo in ('JennyRichards','') 
order by age ASC;
```

Where should i make the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need this query:

```
select 
  FirstName,
  LastName, 
  ReportsTo, 
  Position, 
  Age, 
  case when ReportsTo = 'JennyRichards' then 'CEO' end as BossTitle
from maintable_OFWQC  
where ReportsTo = 'JennyRichards' or ReportsTo is null
order by age
```